# iOS: setting Exclusive Touch to all buttons in a view

Tags: ios, uibutton, touch

My app has many buttons in a Window and I want to set Exclusive Touch all of them together. Do you have any suggestion about this? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to set exclusive touch to all buttons in your app, may be helpful.

```
#import </usr/include/objc/objc-class.h>

static IMP gOringinalWillMoveToSuperview = nil;

static id newMoveToSuperviewPlusSettingExclusiveTouch(id self,SEL selector,...)
{
    va_list arg_list;
    va_start( arg_list,selector);
    gOringinalWillMoveToSuperview(self,selector,arg_list);
    [self setExclusiveTouch:YES];
    return nil;
}

-(void)addSettingExclusiveTouchToAllUIViewMethodWillMoveToSuperview
{
    gOringinalWillMoveToSuperview = class_getMethodImplementation([UIButton class], @selector(willMoveToSuperview:));
    class_replaceMethod([UIButton class], @selector(willMoveToSuperview:), &newMoveToSuperviewPlusSettingExclusiveTouch, "v@:");
}
```

if you don't understand this, you can refer to [this](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/MethodSwizzling) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618474/intercept-method-call-in-objective-c).

Comment: @ZuzooVn you should paste this code before any view that you want to set exclusive touch is created.

Answer (score 2):

Are you just looking for an easy way to set them all at once?

If you have all the buttons in an array (e.g. they're all connected to the same IBOutletCollection) you can use key value coding to set the exclusiveTouch property of the array:

```
[buttonArray setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"exclusiveTouch"];
```

NSArray will then invoke the same method on every item in the array.

Comment: they are not in array. Is possible to set them in XIB?

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)setExclusiveTouchForButtons:(UIView *)myView
{
    for (UIView * v in [myView subviews]) {
        if([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
            [((UIButton *)v) setExclusiveTouch:YES];
        else if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]){
            [self setExclusiveTouchForButtons:v];
        }
    }
}
```

then call this function at viewDidAppear

Answer (score 1):

If these buttons are all in the same view, you can loop through the view's subviews, test for whether the particular subview is a button (or test for a tag if you have one set) and set exclusiveTouch on each.

Answer (score 1):

I just found an answer for this:

```
#pragma mark Set Buttons Exclusive Touch Yes
-(void)setExclusiveTouchForButtons:(UIView *)myView
{
    for (UIView * button in [myView subviews]) {
        if([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
            [((UIButton *)button) setExclusiveTouch:YES];
    }
}
```

[Source](http://ioswithshwet.blogspot.com/2011/10/button-multi-touch-trick.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set exclusiveTouch for ALL UIButtons in your whole application **method swizzling** will be the perfect solution for you.

This answer explains the way very well : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24534814/976246 , and it works perfectly for me.

Also go through this article to know how [***this (http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/)***](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/) tecknique can be used for various purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding buttons pragmatically, then send a message to the button `[button setExclusiveTouch:YES];` for each buttons before adding to its super view. Else if you are using xib, you have to send the same message to the button in viewDidLoad or in loadView.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code in swift that will set exclusive touch to all buttons in your viewcontroller's view

```
for button in self.view.subviews {
    if(button.isKindOfClass(UIButton)){
        (button as! UIButton).exclusiveTouch = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question was asked many years ago, here is a simple way to set  isExclusiveTouch for all subviews that are buttons.  This example shows code for subviews of self.view.   Change self.view to your view of interest.

Seems like cleaner code for anyone with questions on this in the present.

```
            for subview in self.view.subviews
        {
            if subview is UIButton {

                subview.isExclusiveTouch = true
            }
        }
```