# Set exclusive touch on multiple UIViews of the same class

Tags: ios, uiview, touch

I am creating a random number of custom UIViews of the same class, and I'm adding them in the UIViewController's view. I'm assigning them a UITapGestureRecognizer, but I can't seem to make the exclusive touch work:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
   ICCatalogProductView *catalogProductView;
   catalogProductView = [[ICCatalogProductView alloc] init];
   [self.view addSubview:catalogProductView]
   UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(testTouch)];
   [catalogProductView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
   [catalogProductView setExclusiveTouch:YES];
}
```

If i tap the UIViews simultanously, the method is called twice (not the behaviour I want). Is there any elegant method of solving this, or any method at all?

Comment: what actually you want on simultaneous tab.  please specify.

Comment: check this :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919624/ios-setting-exclusive-touch-to-all-buttons-in-a-view

Comment: I want only one touch to be possible, the same behaviour you would have when there are 2 UIButtons with .exclusiveTouch = YES

Answer (score 1):

From the Apple Documentation:

> exclusiveTouch only prevents touches in other views during the time in
>   which there's an active touch in the exclusive touch view. That is, if
>   you put a finger down in an exclusive touch view touches won't start
>   in other views until you lift the first finger. It does not prevent
>   touches from starting in other views if there are currently no touches
>   in the exclusiveTouch view.
>
> To truly make this view the only thing on screen that can receive
>   touches you'd need to either add another view over top of everything
>   else to catch the rest of the touches, or subclass a view somewhere in
>   your hierarchy (or your UIWindow itself) and override
>   hitTest:withEvent: to always return your text view when it's visible,
>   or to return nil for touches not in your text view.

means its only set exclusive in your one view, not if you are touching something outside your view.

Comment: Both UIViews that I'm touching have exclusiveTouch set YES, yet simultaneous touching is possible.

Comment: Basically, touching any view other than ActivityView make the activityView Disappear, you'd need to handle it using the activity View. God forbid, but probably you'd have to create a two separate views. It has something to do with first responder suppose.