# objective c how to set exclusive touch for all UIbuttons on the whole app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton

My app has many buttons through out the application

**I want to set Exclusive Touch all of them together at one time. or all views in the app**

we can set individually by

```
[button setExclusiveTouch:YES];
```

But i want to set at a time for all the buttons in the application

**Can we set all view exclusive touch ?**

any body have any idea please suggest me.

Comment: Could you not just create a subclass of `UIButton` and then you can override the `init` or `buttonWithType:` methods and just set `setExclusiveTouch:` to `YES` as default when a button is created.

Comment: Then he need to change the reference of all the buttons in the application which are already created..

Comment: Why would you do that? Can't you solve your problem by some other way?

Comment: @Apurv not really he could just do `#define UIButton MyButton` so as long as the `MyButton` class is a subclass of `UIButton` it should just replace all `UIButton`s with `MyButton` but keeping the `UIButton` name (I hope you get what I mean) I have done this before in  one of my apps but as I'm not near my Mac to test this I have just done as comment

Comment: I tried it.. But when I do #define UIButton MyButton then in the declaration of @interface MyButton : UIButton, it will try to replace base class (UIButton) with MyButton..

Comment: @Apurv this is just the reason I haven't left as an answer as it is untested, thank you for testing it. When I am near my Mac I will find out exactly what I did, I have tried searching for the link I got it from but it was sometime ago.

Comment: Sure. If you find it, please post it. It may help me for future..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this

```
// Not tested
for (UIView * button in [myView subviews]) {
    if([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        [((UIButton *)button) setExclusiveTouch:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The most elegant and actually the designed way to do this is by using the `appearance` proxy, which is designed to set a defined behaviour or appearance across the board for a given UI component.

```
[[UIButton appearance] setExclusiveTouch:YES];
```

For more information: [Apple Documentation - UIAppearance](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance) and [NSHipster - UIAppearance](http://nshipster.com/uiappearance/)

Comment: Please add some more explanation as to what your code does and how it works, instead of as a single one-liner

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to set `exclusiveTouch` for ALL UIButtons + subclasses in your whole application and not just a single view, you can use [method swizzling](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/).

You use the objc runtime to override `willMoveToSuperview` and set exclusive touch there.
This is very reliable and i've never had any problems using this technique.

I like doing this especially for `UISwitch`, because touch-handling for switches can be a bit tricky and `exclusiveTouch` will help avoid bugs caused by simultaneous taps on different switches

Sample taken from the link above and changed so that `exclusiveTouch` is set:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>


@implementation UIButton (INCButton)

+ (void)load
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        Class class = [self class];

        SEL originalSelector = @selector(willMoveToSuperview:);
        SEL swizzledSelector = @selector(inc_willMoveToSuperview:);

        Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, originalSelector);
        Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, swizzledSelector);

        BOOL didAddMethod =
        class_addMethod(class,
                    originalSelector,
                    method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod),
                    method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));

        if (didAddMethod) {
            class_replaceMethod(class,
                            swizzledSelector,
                            method_getImplementation(originalMethod),
                            method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
        }
    });
}

- (void)inc_willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview
{
    // This is correct and does not cause an infinite loop!
    // See the link for an explanation 
    [self inc_willMoveToSuperview:newSuperview];

    [self setExclusiveTouch:YES];
}

@end
```

Create a category and insert this code for each class you want to alter.

Comment: Is there any issue in using this code in appstore apps ? I mean will apple reject if we use this tecnique ?

Comment: No. this does not use any private API. It's just lower level runtime code which you usually do not need to use when developing an app ;)

Comment: you're welcome. However, you should REALLY follow the link to `NSHipster` i provided in my answer. Just copy-pasting the code is just not enough here - you should really understand what you are doing exactly when swizzling methods - that's a well intended advice!

Comment: ya. I went through the article. Its a well written article and it explains the swizzling tecknique in a simple and perfect way.
And i am now a subscriber of nshipster. I just loved that site.

Answer (score 6):

why so difficult? Make a category

```
@implementation UIButton (ExclusiveTouch)

- (BOOL)isExclusiveTouch
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Cycle through the subviews (recursively) of the top most view, and for each object of type UIButton, apply exclusive touch